# Get-Acl - skip folders without permissions

Tags: permissions, powershell

I am trying to find a way to identify folders that I don't have access to. I have found this command, which recursively reports the permissions of each folder in the folder tree:

```
dir -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq "TRUE" } | get-acl
```

However, it gets stuck on a folder that I *do not* have permissions for, returning this error:

```
get-acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At line:1 char:56
+ dir -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq "TRUE" } | get-acl
+                                                        ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

I know this is due to the user not having permissions on this particular folder. The problem is that the report stops there, regardless of what other folders there may be.

Ultimately, it's these folders that I am interested in - so that I can identify which folders need to review their permissions. So is there any way I can get this command to simply log "unauthorized access", and then continue on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you are viewing the output currently (in the console), in order to get your code to keep going after incurring an exception is to wrap your Get-Acl in a ForEach-Object (aliased as % below} instead of piping directly to Get-Acl

```
dir -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq "TRUE"} | %{get-acl $_.FullName}
```

and you will see in red, errors like:

```
dir : Access to the path 'C:\folder\subfolder' is denied.
```

I wouldn't call this a "report", per se., but technically speaking, that is the answer to the question you're asking.  Hope this helps you get further in your endeavor!

Cheers :)